# Problems displaying UIAlertView from notification when app is closed

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications, push-notification, uialertview

I have the following code that I use for push notifications:

located within my appdelegate.m is the following code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.

//Register to receive notifcations
//-- Set Notification
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
}

[Pushbots getInstance];

NSDictionary * userInfo = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
if(userInfo) {
    // Notification Message
    NSString* notificationMsg = [userInfo valueForKey:@"message"];
    // Custom Field
    NSString* title = [userInfo valueForKey:@"title"];
    NSLog(@"Notification Msg is %@ and Custom field title = %@", notificationMsg , title);
}

return YES;
}

-(void)onReceivePushNotification:(NSDictionary *) pushDict andPayload:(NSDictionary *)payload {
[payload valueForKey:@"title"];
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Alert !" message:[pushDict valueForKey:@"alert"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Thanks !" otherButtonTitles: @"Open",nil];
[message show];
}
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
if([title isEqualToString:@"Open"]) {
    [[Pushbots getInstance] OpenedNotification];
    // set Badge to 0
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
    // reset badge on the server
    [[Pushbots getInstance] resetBadgeCount];
}
}
```

This code works fine when the application is not closed, it presents me  with the notification alert view.

HOWEVER it does not work properly when the application is closed fully and not running in background.

And I dont know what to do about it!

Thanks in advance?

Comment: when app is not running or not in background how code executes?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot since displaying an alert view required the notification invoking some part of your code, however the entry point for your code i.e. where you may first handle anything regarding your notification is on

> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*) launchOptions

which means your app has to be awake in order to show a custom alert view.

For now you will have to settle to the default implementation ios gives you, that is the notification bar at the top.

hope ts useful